# Why is this stored procedure always return 1 for delete operation?

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried many solutions but none of them worked so far. This is my first code that uses OUT parameter in the stored procedure.

When I tested the stored procedure in mySQL WB, it works as expected but when I read that in my C# code, it returns 1 always. However, if I hardcode zero for the stored procedure OUT parameter it reads that values in C#. So it is likely stored procedure is not working as expected but cannot figure out why.

Stored procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`flashLight`@`%` PROCEDURE `DeleteAddress`(IN UserID INT(11),IN AddressID INT(11), OUT AddressDeleted INT(1))
BEGIN
SET @NotLocked = (0); 
SET @AddressIDExists = 1;
SET @Deleted = (1);
CALL IsAddressIDInUse(UserID, AddressID, @AddressIDExists); 
UPDATE address 
SET ADDRESS_DELETED = @Deleted
WHERE 
    ADDRESS_USER_ID = UserID AND 
    ADDRESS_ID = AddressID AND 
    LOCKED = @NotLocked AND 
    @AddressIDExists = 0;   
SET @DeletedRecords = ROW_COUNT();
SET AddressDeleted = IF(@DeletedRecords>0,1,0);
END
```

Stored procedure test code in mySQL WB

```
SET @UserID = 160;
SET @AddressID = 229;
SET @AddressDeleted = '';
CALL DeleteAddress(@UserID,@AddressID,@AddressDeleted);
SELECT @AddressDeleted;
```

AddressDeleted returns correctly (1 or 0) depending on if record deleted or not.

However, if I read it in C# code it returns 1

```
if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand("DeleteAddress", oMySQLConnecion);
                    oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressID", AddressID);
                    MySqlParameter AddressDeleted = new MySqlParameter("@AddressDeleted", MySqlDbType.Int16);
                    AddressDeleted.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                    oCommand.Parameters.Add(AddressDeleted);

                    int result = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    result = Convert.ToInt16(oCommand.Parameters["@AddressDeleted"].Value);

                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.SUCCESS;
                        oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.SUCCESSFULLY_DATA_DELETED);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.ERROR;
                        oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.ERROR_NO_RECORDS_UPDATED);
                    }
                    oMySQLConnecion.Close();
                    return oDBStatus;
                }
```

As I mentioned, If I hardcode zero to the stored procedure, it returns that value. So it is likely stored procedure is having the issue.

Comment: The value returned by row_count() depends on how you configure it while you connect to mysql. `For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the WHERE clause` Check this setting.

Comment: I will check that, but this works fine with mySQL test. I want to see if record updated or not.